# Not able to remove the variables declared inside backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have read many posts about the issue of multiple instances of the same backbone view being instantiated every time and the view hangs around in the DOM even after it's not used any more, and how to fix this by using `this.remove()` and `this.unbind()`

But how to remove the variables declared inside the view, like so:

```
var myview = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#somediv',
    var1 : '',
    var2 : '',
    array1 : [],

    initialize : function() { //init code here 
    },

    render : function() { //rendering code here 
    }
});
```

So my question is, how do i remove instances of those variables declared there: var1, var2, array1. I have to call this view every time i click on a button. And every time i see the previous values of these variables still there. `this.remove()` and `this.unbind()` might just remove the view from DOM and undelegate its events bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties you define inside the `Backbone.View.extend` call are attached to the prototype and thus are shared by all instances of your view (i.e. they're sort of like class properties rather than instance properties). This should be fine with your `var1` and `var2` as you'd just be assigning new values per-instance; the `array1` array and similar properties can be problematic though; suppose you do this:

```
var v = new myview;
v.array1.push('pancakes');
```

Creating a new instance won't deep-copy everything out of the prototype so `v.array1` will refer to the array in the prototype. That means that the next `new myview` will already have `'pancakes'`.

The usual solution is to initialize instance properties in the constructor. For Backbone, the constructor is `initialize`:

```
var myview = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#somediv',
    initialize: function() {
        this.var1 = '';
        this.var2 = '';
        this.array1 = [ ];
    },
    //...
});
```

You can also run into problems with your `el: '#somediv'` as that uniquely identifies a single DOM element. As long as you're removing and recreating that element then you should be okay; I'd recommend letting the view create and destroy its own `el` though, you run into fewer zombies and leaks that way.

Comment: Perfect! I forgot to mention that the array always has the previous elements in it. You mentioned just that!

Comment: So if i wish to remove the previous instance of the view before creating a new one, is just calling `this.remove()` and `this.unbind()` on the view enough?
I'm using require JS library, so I instantiate the view like so: 
    
    `require(['views/someview'], function(view_object) {
           var my_view = new view_object();
    });`

Comment: @RahulDole: Or switch your `on`s to `listenTo`s and then the standard `remove` should be sufficient.

Comment: True but you see, the code in my comment above: `my_view = new view_object();` will instantiate `view_object()` every time. So even if all the bindings have been removed, don't you think this view object will still be hanging around with multiple copies of it?

Comment: No, the local variable would go out of scope and go away.

Comment: perfect, i tried all these cases, and they all work as you suggested here. Thanks a lot!